# Invalid escape sequence при работе с cmake

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake

Здравствуйте!
Есть набор инстркуций, которые мне необходимо сделать.
Сразу скажу, что с cmake и openCV до этого момента с ними не сталкивался.
Задача по инструкции установить 3 переменных через cmd(пути к openCV/soursec,  devkit for ruby).
Пример переменной:

```
set SOURCE_PATH=C:/openCV-2.4.13/opencv/sources
echo %SOURCE_PATH%
C:/openCV-2.4.13/opencv/sources
```

Так вот при попытке выполнить команду:

```
cmake %SOURCE_PATH% -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH% -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=%DEVKIT_PATH%/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=%DEVKIT_PATH%/mingw/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=%DEVKIT_PATH%/mingw/bin/g++.exe -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF
```

Cmake падает с ошибкой

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/user/CMakeFiles/3.6.0-rc1/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/Users/user/CMakeFiles/3.6.0-rc1/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1

  when parsing string

    C:\DevKit/mingw/bin/g++.exe

  Invalid escape sequence \D
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:64 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/user/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

В общем-то я понимаю, что проблема в слеше "С:\", но переменным я указываю явно обычный слеш / как было видно из примера. Как тут быть помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Почему пути выставляете в cmd? Почему не в скрипте cmake?

Comment: Говорю же, с ним я не работал до этого, делаю как указано в инструкции

Comment: Тогда обратитесь с вопросом к тем, кто Вам инструкцию выдал. Если Вы всё делаете по инструкции, а что-то не работает, значит либо Вы что-то не так делаете, либо что-то не так с инструкцией. Учитывая, что Вы с CMake до этого не работали, помочь Вам в рамках ответа будет сложновато.

Comment: в `DEVKIT_PATH` путь с прямым слешем укажи...

Comment: Проблемма была с С:\ перенес файлы на E: все заработало